# LVM entry for logical volume in /etc/fstab - /dev/mapper/group-volume or /dev/group/volume?

Tags: linux, lvm, fstab

I created a logical volume like the following.

```
lvcreate -L 300G MyVolGroup -n homevol
```

As for mounting this volume after initializing a filesystem on it, a few guides I read used `/dev/MyVolGroup/homevol`. However, I noticed the root partition (as part of the default OS install) was mounted using `/dev/mapper/MyVolGroup-root` (this is a vanilla install of Fedora 35 Server).

Both symlink to `../dm-1`. But I'm wondering if there's a good reason to use one over the other (the path under `/dev/MyVolGroup` or the path under `/dev/mapper`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter, you can use either of them. As you found out these are just symlinks and both are created by udev (the `/dev/mapper/<vg>-<lv>` one is created by the `10-dm.rules` rule and the `/dev/<vg>/<lv>` by the `11-dm-lvm.rules`) so these will be created at the same time so there isn't really a reason to prefer one over the other.

I guess the `/dev/<vg>/<lv>` symlink can be seen as a more user friendly and more LVM-specific one and the `/dev/mapper/<vg>-<lv>` can be seen as a more low level one, because all device mapper devices have symlinks in `/dev/mapper`, not only the LVM ones.

And why Anaconda (Fedora installer) prefers the `/dev/mapper` path? I have no idea, it's just used in Blivet (storage library Anaconda uses) as the default path for LVM devices, probably for no particular reason.

Two small notes:

- You definitely should not use the `/dev/dm-X` device, the number is not persistent, `dm-1` will simply be the first device mapper device created.
- Using `UUID` is usually preferred in `fstab`, but this mostly for partitions where `/dev/sda1` is not guaranteed to be the same device between boots. You can use `UUID` here too, but it's not necessary, because the LVM names must be unique in the system so `MyVolGroup-root` will be always the same device.